# Sharepoint 2013- document library form with fields that show up on conditions?

Tags: 2013, column, form, choice-field

Hi firstly I am new on SharePoint and this platform and very eager to learn

Is it possible to make a form that tailors the information entered based on the choices made within the form?

I have a choice column, 100%, and 80%
if 100% is selected then the form remains the same but if 80% is selected two more column should 
appear.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Jquery in your `Edit Form Page` of your document library to show and hide fields based on the choice field selection as the following:

- Navigate to your document library page.
- In the URL address only replace `AllItems.aspx` with `EditForm.aspx`to be like this `http://SiteURL/<Library Name>/Forms/EditForm.aspx`
- From Right Setting Gear > Click on Edit Page.

[image]

- Add web Part > Add Script Editor.

Add the following code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
//Show/hide columns based on Choice Field Selection
$("select[title='Field1']").change(function() {
if ($("select[title='Field1']").val() != "Yes")
{
$('nobr:contains("Field2")').closest('tr').hide();
}
else
{
$('nobr:contains("Field2")').closest('tr').show();
}
});
});

</script>
```

Where `Field1` is the `Choice Field Title` and `Field2` is the `Field Title` that you need to Show / Hide.

**For Example:** the Choice field title in your for is called `Percent` so replace `Field1` in the above code to `Percent`

For more details

- [check Show / Hide fields based on choice field selection using Jquery in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/19/show-hide-fields-based-on-choice-field-selection-using-jquery-in-sharepoint/)
- [SHOW / HIDE FIELDS BASED ON A DROPDOWN SELECTION USING SPUTILITY.JS](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/25/show-hide-fields-based-on-a-drop-down-using-sputility-js/)

Comment: Glad to hear it's worked, should you set this as answer it's the true sign beside my answer , also check this link to know how to do this and get informed badge http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/badges